# How do i fix this warning?

Tags: c

When I compile with `gcc -Wall`, it shows me this warning:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int concatenate(int y, int a)
{
  if (a<y)
  {
    a = a * 10;
    concatenate(y,a);
  }
  else 
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int a = 10;
  scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
  int z = concatenate(y,a);
  int result = x*z + y;
  
  printf("%d\n", result);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: control reaches end of non-void function \[-Wreturn-type\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742581/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-wreturn-type)

Comment: Have you checked which line throws that warning? As a hint: check whether `concatenate` returns something in all cases

Answer (score 1):

In this if statement

```
   if (a<y)
   {
    a= a * 10;
    concatenate(y,a);
   }
```

the function returns nothing. Maybe you ,mean

```
   if (a<y)
   {
    a= a * 10;
    return concatenate(y,a);
   }
```

Comment: that did it thanks . Can you explain to me why does it have to be there

Comment: @newguyhere The function shall return   a value. But  your function doesn't return  anything an the if statement,.

Answer (score 0):

No `return` statement is executed in the `concatenate` function when `a<y` is true.

Have it execute `return` statement even if `a<y` to fix the warning.

My guess is you want

```
    return concatenate(y,a);
```

instead of

```
    concatenate(y,a);
```

Comment: that did it thanks . Can you explain to me why does it have to be there

Comment: @newguyhere It is required to return things. Things are not automatically returned from C functions (except for `main` function in C99 or later)